# How to disable manual window resizing?

Tags: window, resize

How can I disable manual window resizing (by grabbing the edge of the window or otherwise) for one specific window?

CCSM seems to only have rules for setting window sizes, not this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "one specific window"? One type of window (e.g. dialog boxes)? The windows of a particular application? Have you taken a look at CCSM? Maybe disabling or tweaking the Resize plugin will get what you want.

Comment: @waldir I mean one specific application, will check CCSM now